# XPath exclude given class

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract text from a div but excluding a given class:

This is what i'm trying:

```
$pattern = "//div/@title[not(contains (@class, 'second_card local_impact_icon impact-2'))]";
```

but its not excluding the given class, i need to extract just the text of title='' but just from the first div title.

This is the html:

```
<div class="match_info"><div title='Yellow Card' class='local_impact_icon impact-1'></div><div title='Red Card' class='second_card local_impact_icon impact-2'></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following XPath

```
//div/div[not(contains (@class, 'second_card local_impact_icon impact-2'))]/@title
```

returns

```
title="Yellow Card"
```

Simplified explanation - just select the div that doesn't contain the class you want to exclude and retrieve the title attribute for this div only. When you set this exclude at the position `../@title` you already are at the title-attributes of both divs.

And as the question is how to retrieve the text - in given example

```
string(//div/div[not(contains (@class, 'second_card local_impact_icon impact-2'))]/@title)
```

returns `Yellow Card`

Comment: @Marx Glad that helped you. Was just about to ask if you want to exclude only divs that have **both** classes or just every div that has at least the class "second_card" as I thought maybe the space in the contains could be an issue. Then it could be better to have two "not(contains)" statements checking for both classes separately.